# Python read values from multiple rows based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have one csv file(2 different samples)

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      Date/Time     ID  C_1 C_2  C_3   C_4 C_5 C_6  C_7  C_8 C_9 C_10
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  136 101 2028  61    4   3   18   0    0   2    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  24  101 2029  65    0   0   0    1    1   NA   1
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  16  101 2022  89    0   0   0    0    0   NA   7
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  136 101 2024  90    0   0   0    0    0   NA   3
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  24  101 2026  87    0   1   8    0    0   9    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:58"  136 101 2023  33    0   1   87   0    0   2    2"""), sep="\s+")

dfb = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      Date/Time     ID  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4 C_5 C_6  C_7  C_8 C_9 C_10
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  24  101 2029  65    0   0   0    1    1   NA   1
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  136 101 2028  61    4   3   18   0    0   2    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  16  101 2022  89    0   0   0    0    0   NA   7
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  136 101 2024  90    0   0   0    0    0   NA   3
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  136 101 2023  33    0   1   87   0    0   2    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:58"  24  101 2026  87    0   1   8    0    0   9    2"""), sep="\s+")

dfc = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
      Date/Time     ID  C_1 C_2  C_3   C_4 C_5 C_6  C_7  C_8 C_9 C_10
"18/06/2023 3:51:53"  136 101 2028  61    4   3   18   0    0   2    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  24  101 2029  65    0   0   0    1    1   NA   1
"18/06/2023 3:51:54"  136 102 2045  61    2   3   4    5    6   7    8
"18/06/2023 3:51:55"  16  101 2022  89    0   0   0    0    0   NA   7
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  136 101 2024  90    0   0   0    0    0   NA   3
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  16  102 2022  89    0   0   0    0    0   NA   11
"18/06/2023 3:51:56"  136 101 2024  90    0   0   0    0    0   NA   3
"18/06/2023 3:51:57"  24  101 2026  87    0   1   8    0    0   9    2
"18/06/2023 3:51:58"  24  102 2045  44    43  42  41   40   39  38   37
"18/06/2023 3:51:59"  136 101 2023  33    0   1   87   0    0   2    2"""), sep="\s+")
```

I am trying to read the row values(few columns) using below conditions-

- Check the ID='16', if match read 'Date/Time', 'C_1' and 'C_10' column values.
- Find the first previous(from ID='16') row location where ID='136' and read column values from C_2 to C_8.
- Find the first previous OR first next (from ID='16') row location where ID='24' and read the 'C_9' column value(whichever is not empty out of 2 rows OR leave empty if both are empty).

Output -

```
      Date/Time     ID  C_1  C_2   C_3  C_4 C_5 C_6  C_7  C_8 C_9 C_10
18/06/2023  3:51:55 16  101  2028   61   4   3   18   0    0   9   7
```

Comment: "first previous OR first next" how do you decide which one takes precedence?

Comment: also, not to be pedantic, but your examples aren't CSVs

Comment: Hi @Mark..previous row will take precedence

Comment: @RKIDEV to be clear, you show 2 dataframes as 2 independent examples?

Comment: @mozway..I have edited the samples to my original post.. yeah there are 2 different samples of the same dataframe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, slice the three possibilities, use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html), then aggregate into a single row with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
m = df['ID'].eq('16')
m1 = df['ID'].isin(['16', '136'])
m2 = df['ID'].isin(['16', '24'])

cols = ['Date/Time', 'ID', 'C_1', 'C_10']

pd.concat([df.loc[m1].mask(m).ffill().loc[m, cols+['C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5', 'C_6', 'C_7', 'C_8']],
           df.loc[m2].mask(m).ffill().loc[m, cols+['C_9']],
           df.loc[m2].mask(m).bfill().loc[m, cols+['C_9']],
          ]).groupby(level=0).first()
```

*NB. precedence is given by the order of the slices in [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), the first non-NaN value will be kept. Also, if you have multiple possible values in C_1/C_2, you should replace `ffill`/`bfill` by `.groupby(['ID', 'C_1', 'C_10']).ffill()`/`bfill()`.*

Output:

```
            Date/Time   ID    C_1  C_10     C_2   C_3  C_4  C_5   C_6  C_7  C_8  C_9
2  18/06/2023 3:51:53  136  101.0   2.0  2028.0  61.0  4.0  3.0  18.0  0.0  0.0  9.0
```

##### solution per C_1 group

```
m = df['ID'].eq('16')
m1 = df['ID'].isin(['16', '136'])
m2 = df['ID'].isin(['16', '24'])

cols = ['Date/Time', 'ID', 'C_1', 'C_10']

tmp = df.mask(m).fillna({'C_1': df['C_1']})

pd.concat([tmp.loc[m1].groupby(df['C_1']).ffill().loc[m, cols+['C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5', 'C_6', 'C_7', 'C_8']],
           tmp.loc[m2].groupby(df['C_1']).ffill().loc[m, cols+['C_9']],
           tmp.loc[m2].groupby(df['C_1']).bfill().loc[m, cols+['C_9']],
          ]).groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output (using `dfc` as input):

```
            Date/Time   ID    C_1  C_10     C_2   C_3  C_4  C_5   C_6  C_7  C_8   C_9
3  18/06/2023 3:51:53  136  101.0   2.0  2028.0  61.0  4.0  3.0  18.0  0.0  0.0   9.0
5  18/06/2023 3:51:54  136  102.0   8.0  2045.0  61.0  2.0  3.0   4.0  5.0  6.0  38.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mozway, unfortunately it's not working completely. It's reading `'Date/Time', 'C_1' and 'C_10'` values where `ID=136` instead of `ID=16`.

Comment: Actually I want to group by column `C_1` first as I have different `C_1` (like 102, 103 etc), then want to check the above conditions for each individual `C_1` values. As you suggested replace `ffill/bfill` by `.groupby(['ID', 'C_1', 'C_10']).ffill()/bfill()`, I tried that but getting error `(['ID', 'C_1', 'C_10'] not in index)`

Comment: after adding `[df.loc[m, cols],` at the beginning of the concat() function above it's reading `'Date/Time', 'C_1' and 'C_10'` values where `id=16`. Still looking for the solution with groupby().

Comment: @RKIDEV can you edit you question to add a third example with varying C_1?

Comment: I added a solution per group. Regarding the KeyError, this is due to losing the grouping column in the `groupby`, you can go around it using `groupby(df['C_1'])`.

Comment: I have added one more sample with varying `C-1`..also thank you the updated solution, it's working fine. I just added the `df.loc[m, cols]` to read the values of `'Date/Time', 'C_1' and 'C_10'` where `ID=16` as I have mentioned in my previous comment.